# Avoid functions on Utilities.jsonStringify

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an javascript Object with some proptotyped functions, like that:

```
function Test() {

    this.name = "A name";

    Test.prototype.prototypedFunction = function() {
        var a = "anything";
    }

    this.normalMethod = function(){
        var b = "another thing";
    };
}
```

When call Utilities.jsonStringify() on any object of "Test" type, all functions are stringfyed, like that:

{"prototypedFunction":"\nfunction () {\n    var a \u003d \"anithing\";\n}\n","name":"A name","normalMethod":"\nfunction () {\n    var b \u003d \"another thing\";\n}\n"}

But since I will pass this object to a rest service, it doesn't make sense to send functions, just the data. What I would expect is just that:

{"name":"A name"}

So, is it possible to Utilities.jsonStringify to avoid stringify functions, or, at least avoid Prototyped functions?

Thanks,

Mael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSON.stringify instead and it should do what you want.